# Sugestões de novas comunidades antes de chegar a proposta no area51

Tags: suporte

Eu gostaria de fomentar a criação de novas comunidades, em especial na lingua inglesa, dentre elas comunidades especificas sobre Controle de Versão, entre outras, como a que já sugeri para o Arduino no Brasil.

Há algum meio de se discutir tais criações que seja mais indicado? Pensei em começar pelo chat, mas não achei como convidar diretamente pessoas que identifiquei serem adequadas ao processo através do perfil.